# Is it appropriate to wrap each navigation element in a div?

Tags: css, html, semantic-markup

I'm learning HTML + CSS and working on a website where I need to have a vertical navigation bar on the left side which will have four elements which can be interacted with. Is it standard practice to wrap each of these four elements with a div or is there a more elegant or semantic way to solve this problem? I will want each element to have unique on-click functions associated with them, which is why I thought giving them divs and classes would make the most sense for interacting with them later.

Thanks!

Comment: Navigations are essentially lists..so go for `ul` and `li`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/34bowu5h/9/)

**HTML structure:**
There are many ways to achieve a vertical navigation.
The most common would be to use `ul` and `li`:

```
<div id="lnav_container">
    <ul id="lnav">
        <li class="lnav_item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="lnav_item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="lnav_item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="lnav_item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also very common to have `a` tags inside `li`.

**Styling:**
You can get rid of the bullets by having `list-style-type: none;` for the `ul`.
You can give them different style on hover by using `:hover` selector to make it more interactive.

```
.lnav_item {
    width: 74%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.lnav_item:first-child {margin-top: 0px;}
.lnav_item.selected {width: 86%;}
.lnav_item a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 8px 5px 5px 0px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px 12px 12px 2px;
}
.lnav_item.selected a {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.lnav_item:hover a {background-color: orange;}
```

To get rid of `a` underline use `text-decoration: none;` and override its default coloring if you wish.

**Javascript (jQuery):**
It'll be easy to bind `clickListener` to the items:

```
$('.lnav_item a').on('click', function() {
    //$(this) item is clicked, do whatever you want
    $('.lnav_item').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to give each of the navigation items a different style, etc, you can achieve it different ways:

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/34bowu5h/10/)

1. You can use CSS' `nth-child()` selector:

   ```
   .lnav_item:nth-child(2):hover a{background-color: #252F1D;}
   .lnav_item:nth-child(3):hover a{background-color: white;}
   ```
2. If you're doing it in jQuery, alternatively you can use the function with parameter (index) and maybe use `eq` if needed.

   ```
   $('.lnav_item > a').each(function(index) {
       if(index == 0) {
           //give it a different onClick, CSS rule, etc
       }
       //and so on
   });
   ```

   - **`index` is zero-based, but `nth-child` starts from one.**

Comment: Bind the click listener to an `a` tag inside the `li`. This way it is accessible to users who are using keyboard only to navigate your site.

Comment: If I would like each of the four elements to have a different hover/on.click event associated with it, how do I write that to avoid repeating myself for each element? edit: sorry, edit of code incoming.

`.link1 {
 background: #505050;
 :hover {
  background: #252F1D;
 }

}

.link2 {
 background: #505050;
 :hover {
  background: white;
 }

}`

Comment: just answered my question, i think, maybe you can tell me if it's an appropriate solution. using a sass mixin:

`@mixin hover-util($dback, $hback){
 background: $dback;
 :hover {
  background: $hback;
 }
}`

Comment: Check the edit for your first question. I'm not a sass expert, so I don't know if it's appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The typical HTML5 markup for a site navigation menu would be a [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-nav-element) that contains an [`ul` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you can get your CSS/JS to work with this markup (+ `class` attributes or whatever you need), great.
If you need more elements, add `div` and/or `span` elements: they are [meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868474/1591669), so they don’t change the semantics of your document.

Answer (score 0):

NAV elements are simply LISTS.

You don't need to wrap them in anything.

Here's an example of my own Navigation Panel  (I also placed it on the left-hand side of my screen)

```
      <nav>
        <ul style="list-style: none">
            <h3>Main Menu</h3>
            <li style="font-size: 100%"><b>Article 1</b></li>
            <ul style="list-style: none">
            <br>
                <dt>
                <li style="font-size: 100%"><a href="Article 1.1">Article 
                                            1.1</a>
                </li>
                <br>
                <li style="font-size: 100%"><a href="Article 1.2">Article 
                                            1.2</a>
                </li>
                <br>
                </dt>
            </ul>
            <br>
    </nav>
```