# Should I use an image map to create a navigation bar? If not, what would be a better option?

Tags: html, image, navigation, navigationbar, imagemap

I have recently started to learn web design, so, please bear with me if my question is a bit trivial. My question is: Should I use an Image map to create a navigation bar? If not, what would be a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use an image map if you *have* to use an image.

Better option: Use appropriate markup and style it with CSS.

[Typical HTML5 markup for navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30026310/1591669) would be:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

With CSS, you can remove the default list styling and make the links appear horizontally. There are various ways to achieve this, e.g.:

```css
nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```