# Screen reader stops when it reaches a span element

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover

I'm doing some screen reader usability testing and I was wondering if someone could explain to me why a screen reader stops when it reaches a `<span />` element.

Example:

```
<h1><span class="style1">Today</span> is a wonderful <span class="style2">day</span></h1>
```

The screen reader will read "Today" and then stop rather than reading the entire `<h1 />` text.

Note: I'm using the voice over available on an iPad in the Settings > General > Accessibility menu.

Comment: Same issue (for `span`, `strong`, `b`, etc.) discussed in the question: [Making an h2 tag with a strong tag inside accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35444747/1591669).

Comment: role="text" in a span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by @vanita and by my comment in [Making an h2 tag with a strong tag inside accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444747/making-an-h2-tag-with-a-strong-tag-inside-accessible#comments-35451571) from three years ago, that's just how VoiceOver works.  There could be some semantic significance among the elements so VoiceOver is going to stop on each one.

There is a workaround, though, but it's undocumented and only affects VoiceOver (not JAWS or NVDA).  Use `role="text"`.  However, since it's undocumented, you run the risk of it not working at some point in the future.

Be careful how you use it because you don't want to lose the semantic meaning of the heading.  Let's start with the original problem, something like this:

```
<h1>hello <strong>there</strong> world</h1>
<h1>hello <span class="myclass">there</span> world</h1>
```

It doesn't matter if the embedded element is semantic (<strong>) or not (<span>).

`role="text"` should **not** be put on the <h1> directly because that would remove the semantic meaning of the heading:

```
<h1 role="text">hello <strong>there</strong> world </h1> <!-- DO NOT DO THIS -->
```

Instead, embed all the inner text in a <span> and specify `role="text"` on the inner span.

```
<h1><span role="text">hello <strong>there</strong> world</span></h1>
```

This will cause "hello there world" to be read as one element and will still say the entire thing is a heading.

Answer (score 0):

This is how some screenreaders behave when they encounter elements within other elements. People who regularly use assistive tech like screenreaders will probably be used to this, so I would suggest leaving it as is.

Comment: Is this really the generally accepted answer to this problem?

Comment: Until someone really creative thinks of a better solution I guess it is.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use alternative, hidden content.

For example: 
`<h1>This is a <b>bolder</b> word.</h1>`
VO might only read out "This is a" and stopped

Add hidden content:

```
<div>
  <h1 aria-hidden="true">This is a <b>bolder</b> word.</h1>
  <span class="hidden-text"> This is a bolded word.</span>
</div>
```

css style for `.hidden-text`:

```
.hidden-text{
  position absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

The reason you'd wrap them in the same `div` is so that it allows the voice over focus box will locate the area appropriately.

This works for me, I hope it works for you too!